# Lib Caffe (C++): input_blobs()[0] causes bottom shape error after first call

Tags: c++, caffe

I am trying to use Lib Caffe to extract features from images, so I can use it for other purposes on my project.

My Caffe Neural Network works fine for the first image, but at the second image, it throws me the following error:

```
Check failed: bottom[0]->shape() == bottom[i]->shape() bottom[0]: 87122736 0 85536896 0 (37632), bottom[1]: 1 3 112 112 (37632)
```

Both first and second images are the same and their shapes are the (112 x 112) with 3 channels.

**The code**

```
Caffe::set_mode(Caffe::CPU);
my_net.reset(new caffe::Net<float>(arch, caffe::TEST));
my_net->CopyTrainedLayersFrom(model);

for(int i=0; i<num_images;i++) {
    Blob<float> *my_blob = my_net->input_blobs()[0]; 

    // accessing blob attributes just for debugging purposes
    // 1 after first call OK, 87122736 at second call (?)
    int batch_size = my_blob->num(); 
    // 3 after first call OK, 0 at second call (?)
    int channels = my_blob->channels(); 
    // 112 after first call OK, 85536896 at second call (?)
    int height = my_blob->height(); 
    // 112 after first call OK, 0 at second call (?)
    int width = my_blob->width(); 

    my_blob->set_cpu_data(images[i]);
    my_net->Forward();

    //delete my_blob; <-- IT WAS CAUSING THE PROBLEM
}
```

How can I just feed the Net so I can run it over the next images? How to make input_blobs()[0] points to the same memory block as the first attempt? As you can see, the attributes are different for the same parameters `input_blobs()[0]`.

Comment: "I am forwarding my net" - what's a "net"? What are you trying to do? What library are you using? Why are you posting code snippets rather than a [mcve]?  What are the errors you are getting? What compiler and language standard are you using? It's entirely unclear to me what you are asking (and thus I voted to close as Unclear).

Comment: I understand your point, but for those who have knowledge about Neural Networks, just saying 'net' is enough. The same happens with 'forwarding' for those who have knowledge about the lib Caffe. The error was clear: 'the function input_blobs() return different pointers after first call'. The language used is at the keywords at the bottom. Well... I will update the question. I am sure a lot of others  have the same problem. Regards

Comment: @JesperJuhl is it better now?

Comment: *I* think it is.

Comment: I am in agreement. May still be helped by a [mcve], but I don't know caffe, so perhaps all the required information IS there, but I suspect not.

Comment: @user4581301It would be impossible to show a minimal example, because to use the lib Caffe you need to compile it, link it to your project and do a lot of other configs. I still say that the information shown is enough for those who have knowledge about Neural Networks and Caffe. Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION FOUND**

In previous release of Caffe, I use to allocate a new input blob, set its data, push it back to a boottom and than use it as bellow:

```
// allocate new input blob
Blob<float> *my_blob = new Blob<float>(1, 1, width, height);
// set its data
feature_blob->set_cpu_data(image[i]);
// push it back to a bottom
std::vector<Blob<float>*> feature_botton;
feature_botton.push_back(feature_blob);
// use the blob forwarding the network
loss=0;
const std::vector<Blob<float>*>& feature_points(
feature_extraction_net->Forward(feature_botton, loss));

// deallocate memory
feature_botton.clear();
delete feature_blob;
```

The problem is with a newer release of Caffe, I don't need to deallocate memory. Actually this was the problem root. I just don't delete the blob anymore.

The solution is posted in the git forum of the lib ([solution](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/6670))